# USB created from using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool cannot boot

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I try to install windows 7 using a bootable usb. I use the Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool and run it without any problem. Then I reboot my computer and set the first bootable device to "USB HDD" and disable all other devices. However, it doesn't get me to the installation page but still load the existing Windows 7 from my hard drive.

I don't understand two things:

1. Why the computer doesn't boot from the usb.
2. Why it can still load my existing Windows 7. I did disable all devices except "USB HDD" so it should either try to boot from usb or if it cannot recognize or boot from usb then stop prompting no bootable device.

NOTE: unlike many other questions, I don't have problem with bootsec (I guess it is run as part of the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool as I don't need to install it or run it separately at all). I am running the program in 64bit Windows 7 and try to create a bootable usb for the same 64bit Windows 7.

I only format my usb uing FAT32 quick format. I don't know whether this matters or not.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Windows 7 gets stubborn about booting, instead of disabling all but the USB boot option, try using the F9, or F10 key during boot up to get to advanced boot options, and force it to boot to the USB drive. If I'm planning on doing a new installation, I normally do a Low Level format on the drive first anyway, that will wipe out the drive, and give you a clean/raw drive to work with. That will also eliminate the booting to an existing installation issue.